# append overlay to content behind bootstrap 3 mobile nav toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting the below *(within footer.php)* and no such luck.

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.navbar-collapse').click(function(){
$(function() {

    var docHeight = $(document).height();

   $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");

           $("#overlay")
            .height(docHeight)
            .css({
                 'opacity' : 0.7,
                 'position': 'fixed',
                 'top': 0,
                 'left': 0,
                 'background-color': 'black',
                 'width': '100%',
                 'z-index': 5000
              });
        }); 
    });
});
```

**Mark-Up:**

```
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
```

Any suggestions on how to fade or grey out the background or all body content when nav toggle is triggered and present -- the goal is to have the mobile navigation not be opacity but everything else to be opacity. Cheers for any pointers. *(Wordpress website)* Eg. Click navigation > nav toggle appears > body and all content behind it and elsewhere is #000 opacity .7 while nav toggle is present, once closed, restored back to original state without opacity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully. can you describe it differently, or perhaps make a drawing of what you want each state to look like?

Comment: I want to simply darken all website content and elements once the navigation div is toggled to present. So that everything else is darkened or has opacity to lower then 1 EXCEPT the present nav. Does that make since now?

Comment: can you put the dysfunctional code into jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a good start would be changing your jquery to the following:

```
$(function() {

  var docHeight = $(window).height();
  $('.navbar-collapse').click(function(){
     $("<div id='overlay'>")
      .height(docHeight)
      .css({
           'opacity' : 0.7,
           'position': 'fixed',
           'top': 0,
           'left': 0,
           'background-color': 'black',
           'width': '100%',
           'z-index': 5000
      }).appendTo('body');
  });
  
});
```

## edit

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7t4zz0jw/10/)

check this out, it's mostly css but i think it's what you want.

```
$(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function() {
        $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
    })
});
```

then css

```
body.menu-open:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and helping me clean my script.. but this sill didn't darken the content behind nav when nav present. (didn't work)

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for..! the only problem is it's also effecting my nav itself with this implementation in my environment possibly because of body tag looking into it now.